# Random glitchess in graphics in every game

Tags: graphics-card

So for the past week I've been getting random glitches in my graphics in every game, only when I'm in game. I've tried re-installing the latest drivers with no joy. Anything else I can try?

It shows up in my recordings too, see here for example: http://www.twitch.tv/alexcroox/v/9835271

GTX 780ti

Comment: Sounds like your video card is overheating.  Does it happen right at the beginning of a game, or only after a certain amount of time?

Comment: Like what Frank said, install speedFan or similar program and note down what the temperature is.

Comment: Temp is about 65 degrees so I don't think it's that. I've also reseated it.